# |ProgramFilesFolder| evaluates to AppData\Local\Programs\

Tags: windows-7, wix, uac

I am implementing a single package that support both Per-User & Per-Machine installation in WiX using `WixUI_Advanced`. When I select *Install for all users on this machine* - `[ProgamFilesFolder]` evaluates to `AppData\Local\Programs` instead of `C:\Program Files`.

Note that UAC prompt for elevation comes up only after the target directory selection - which I think is causing this problem due to UAC virtualization.

How can i get true Program Files directory?
Another workaround could be - to change the dialog order to show directory selection dialog after feature selection dialog whose next button invokes the UAC elevation prompt.
Or to prompt for UAC elevation before `[ProgramFilesFolder]` is evaluated for target location but only when the user has chose per-machine install.

**Update**: Currently I use: `[%ProgramFiles]` -- environment variable (breaks upon install of x86 on x64)

**Update II**: Now I am using the registry value of `ProgramFilesDir` at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

Comment: You can convert msi to exe using .dontnetinstaller tool and then UAC prompt will always come as soon as you execute the setup.

Comment: negative - UAC prompt should only come-up if the user chooses to install per-machine.

Comment: Yes. UAC will come only if user does not have admin permissions on the server

Answer (score 0):

`WixUI_Advanced` depends on a `Directory` element with `Id='APPLICATIONFOLDER'` to configure where your application is being installed. The `ALLUSERS` property is then used to configure the path to install to the correct location. A lot of this is detailed in the [WixUI_Advanced Dialog Set](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_advanced.htm) help topic. None of that will change the value of `ProgramFilesFolder`.

PS: The `[%ProgramFiles]` environment is a less robust way to access the `ProgramFilesFolder`. Instead, you can use `[ProgramFilesFolder]` to get the value defaulted in the Windows installer.

Comment: <CustomAction Id="Overwrite_WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" Property="WixPerMachineFolder" Value="[%ProgramFiles]\$(var.Product.Name)" Execute="immediate" />
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="Overwrite_WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" />
    </InstallUISequence>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="Overwrite_WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

I am using this.

Comment: Yes, that would mess up WixUI_Advanced's design. I would recommend setting the `WixAppFolder` property as documented to control the defaults instead.

Comment: [%ProgramFiles] is a problem - when installing x86 on x64.

Comment: I do not know why - my guess is UAC visualization - [ProgramFilesFolder] = `AppData\Local\Programs` for me.

Comment: @RobMensching WixAppFolder only controls scope, not architecture.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh ProgramFilesFolder and ProgramFiles64Folder have invalid (per-user) values before InstallScopeDlg is filled by user, so it is impossible to use them to configure defaults for AdvancedDialogSet - its actions are happening too early.